# Custom DataAnnotations to Fluent-API

Tags: .net-core, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-2.1

For my ef core appliation I created some classes which are constrained by `DataAnnotations`. i. e. I had to define a custom attribute which ensures that a `IList` will have at least one item in it.

Custom `ValidationAttribute`:

```
public class ListLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }

    public ListLengthAttribute()
    {
        Min = 0;
        Max = int.MaxValue;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        IList listValue = value as IList;

        if (listValue != null)
        {
            int listLength = listValue.Count;
            return listLength >= Min && listLength <= Max;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The resulting class might look something like:

```
public class Dummy 
{
    [ListLength( Min = 1, ErrorMessage = "Each dummy should contain at least 1 foo." )]
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to completely move away from `DataAnnotations` and use the (ef-core) Fluent-API.

Is there any way to map the above constrain while using the `ModelBuilder` in my `EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext` class?

Maybe something like:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Dummy>().Property( d => d.Foos ).MinLength(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You mainly need to understand the purposes of each of these. Data annotations are used to define rules and constraints for your model. These can be used for server side, client side **and** database validations (for the **relevant parts**). A custom `ValidationAttribute` can be used for server side validations.

Fluent API is used purely to translate into database configuration. Only attributes such as `MaxLength(n)` have a direct meaning in client, server and database side (`varchar(n)`). So, these attributes do have direct alternates in fluent API. However, EF will not automatically understand what your custom validation means in your database. For instance, in your case the validation seems to be translated to a one to one relation when max length is 1. So, for this perceptual example you can set a one to one in fluent API. EF can not check the code and understand the validation's intent in a situation like this.

For all other values of max length and min length, there is no mapping configuration that can be set in a database. Hence, fluent API can't have a mapping functionality for it. If the database you use does have a similar feature, you can look into the documentation of it's EF library for the mapping functionality.

Based on why you would like to move away from data annotations, what you are really looking for maybe fluent validations. You can look into this library and [this git repo](https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders/) that provides a sample clean implementation of of models while using this library.