# How to achieve custom validation using the Fluent API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fluent

I Have a class Competator

```
internal class Competator
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }  

        [MustBe12AndAbove]
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
```

For the age field I have written a custom validation as in the code below and using it during the competator registration

```
internal class MustBe12AndAbove:ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var Competator = (Competator)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

            return (Competator.age < 12) ? new ValidationResult("The competator must be above 12 to register")
                                           : ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

But since i have not used the DataAnnotation in any of the entity I need to use as the Fluent API method something like as in the below.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Competator>()
                .Property(c => c.age)
                .MustBe12AndAbove();
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking - no, it's not possible.
The main problem is that `ValidationAttribute` is server-side validation, while the Fluent API you are speaking about is database configuration - will be translated into database schema and constraints.

The tool https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/ might make you life easier.

See for more detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54353112/2091519

Comment: You have to consider the question of "Where to do the validation?"
a) Database level with table/field constraints b) Database level with triggers (not recommended), c) Intercepting the EF SaveChanges method (not recommended) d) EF C# model attributes (usually for simple checks like required, complex checks not recommended), e) Before placing the object in a list of EF objects to save using something like a custom Object.IsValid() method, f) At the API level well before you even do any EF work.

Comment: You also need to answer what to do when there is a validation error and does it need to be shown to the user?  For example, C# field attributes are good but result is not-user friendly messages.  A user would rather see "The product could not be saved because its dimensions exceed the maximum box size." instead of "Save failed. Length outside range".